# Iterate over grouped object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a object with grouped data mapped by means of lodash groupBy function,
what would be the best way to iterate over the collection and to retreive the following information:

- totalProductNumber,
- totalProductSum = Sum(productsNumberInGroup *
  price)
- productsNumberPerGroup

So the output could be

```
let result = {
totalProductNumber: 8,
totalProductSum: 17,
productsNumberPerGroup: [{1:2}, {2:3}, {3:3}] // or sth. like this
}
```

```
interface IProduct {
  name: string;
  color: string;
  price: string;
 id: number
 }

    const products = {
  "1": [{
      "name": "Jim",
      "color": "blue",
      "price": 1,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Jim",
      "color": "blue",
      "price": 1,
      "id": 1
    }
  ],
  "2": [{
      "name": "Eddie",
      "color": "green",
      "price": 2,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Eddie",
      "color": "green",
      "price": 2,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Eddie",
      "color": "green",
      "price": 2,
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "3": [{
      "name": "Ela",
      "color": "pink",
      "price": 3,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Ela",
      "color": "pink",
      "price": 3,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Ela",
      "color": "pink",
      "price": 3,
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

My assumption is to use Object.entries or Object.values

```
  let totalSum: number;
  let totalPrices: number[];
Object.values(products)
      .map((prod) => {
        (prod as IProduct[]).map((p) => {
            this.totalPrices.push(Number(p.price)); // here getting Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
        });
      });
```

Comment: You only declared totalPrices, you didn't assign a value to it. Try assigning an empty array to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With mutable style

```js
interface IProduct {
  name: string
  color: string
  price: number
  id: number
}

type Products = Record<string, IProduct[]>

const products: Products = { ... }

let totalProductNumber = 0
let totalProductSum = 0
let productsNumberPerGroup: [string, number][] = []

Object.entries(products).map(([grpId, grpProducts]) => {
  totalProductNumber = totalProductNumber + grpProducts.length
  totalProductSum = totalProductSum + grpProducts.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.price, 0)
  productsNumberPerGroup = [...productsNumberPerGroup, [grpId, grpProducts.length]]
})

console.log(totalProductNumber) // 8
console.log(totalProductSum) // 17
console.log(productsNumberPerGroup) //[ [ '1', 2 ], [ '2', 3 ], [ '3', 3 ] ]
```

### With immutable style

```js
type Result = [
  totalProductNumber: number,
  totalProductSum: number,
  productsNumberPerGroup: [string, number][]
]
const initial: Result = [0, 0, []]

const [totalNum, totalSum, prdPerGrp] = Object.entries(products).reduce<Result>(
  ([num, sum, perGrp], [grpId, grpProducts]) => {
    return [
      num + grpProducts.length,
      sum + grpProducts.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.price, 0),
      [...perGrp, [grpId, grpProducts.length]]
    ]
  },
  initial
)

console.log(totalNum) // 8
console.log(totalSum) // 17
console.log(prdPerGrp) // [ [ '1', 2 ], [ '2', 3 ], [ '3', 3 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do two changes

```
let totalPrices: number[];
```

to

```
let totalPrices: number[] = [];
```

One more change in interface

```
interface IProduct {
  name: string;
  color: string;
  price: string;
  id: number
}
```

change

```
price: string;
```

to

```
price: number;
```